# rejected master -> master (fetch first) facing this issues in GitHub

Tags: github, push

I face this problem in GitHub. I can't push my code in here. It showing me this rejected master -> master (fetch first). I faced big trouble, for this reason.

Comment: Can you please paste the whole error your are getting? some screenshot

Comment: provide a copy of the error, else no one can help

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem and used the following command and it worked**

`git fetch origin master`